# Google Analytics PHP API - Get User Email

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

When authenticating in google for google Analytics I want to get the user's email id as well is it possible to do it so how can I solve this

Below is the code I have used to authenticate and save the access_token

```
      $scope =implode(' ', array(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY,Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY));

    $this->client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google/callback');
    $this->client->addScope($scope);
    $this->client->setAccessType("offline");

    // Handle authorization flow from the server.
    if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $auth_url = $this->client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));

    } else {
        $this->client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $this->client->getAccessToken();

        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']['refresh_token'])) {

            $this->googledbsave_model->create_google_cred($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['access_token']);


           if($_SESSION['id']==19){

                $access_token =  $_SESSION['access_token'];

                $update_token = array(

                    'access_token' => $access_token['access_token'],
                    'token_type' => $access_token['token_type'],
                    'expires_in' => $access_token['expires_in'],
                    'created' => $access_token['created']
                );

                $get_prof = $this->googledbsave_model->update_subadmin($_SESSION['id'], $update_token);

            }


        } else {
            $this->googledbsave_model->create_google_cred($_SESSION['id'], $_SESSION['access_token']);
            $this->revokeToken();

            $_SESSION['has_error'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['error_message'] = "Cannot Syncronise Account Properly... Please Authenticate Again";
        }


        $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/google/getProfileIDs';
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Without seeing that we cannot help you. Please share some code you have written

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are authenticating with the Google Analytics API the easiest way would be to go though the management protocol.   Do an [account summaries list](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list)

```
$accounts = $analytics->management_accountSummaries->listManagementAccountSummaries();
```

Technically this method is used to list the accounts the current authenticated user has access to.  However it has a little bonus in that it also returns their email address in the username field.

```
{  
   "kind":"analytics#accountSummaries",
   "username":"xxxx@gmail.com",
   "totalResults":14,
   "startIndex":1,
   "itemsPerPage":1000,
   "items":[  
      {      
       ....
      }]
}
```

You can do the same with the Google calendar API which you are also using.  By doing a [calendar get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/get) on the primary calendar

```
$calendar = $service->calendars->get('primary');
```

The primary calendar is the main calendar for all users.

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#calendar",
 "etag": "\"E756z8zuickcYzaOnj8krCN4-Pk\"",
 "id": "xxxx@gmail.com",
 "summary": "laurly71@gmail.com",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Copenhagen"
}
```

A lot of the Google APIs have this hidden feature you just have to figure out which method you need to call to get the information.